# Is across the window/towards the window the expression in this context?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

Let's I am in a room with a window and I want to describe the direction of the wind with respect to the window, Can I use these these expressions

> The direction of the wind is **towards the window**.(wind coming in the room through the window)
>
> The direction of the wind is **across the window** (wind's direction being parallel to the window or in mathematical sense being at a 90 degree  angle to the direction mentioned in expression 1).

Is this how a native english speaker would describe them?

Comment: I'd simplify - The wind blows in through/past the window. Only weather forecasters really need to be any more precise.

Comment: @Dude Maybe you were thinking of "along the side of" (or simply "alongside"). I'm not sure if you were trying to understand the prepositions *towards* and *across* or you were aiming at precision writing. (I guess it's the first.) I believe that in technical writing, using *perpendicular* and *parallel* would be fine.

Comment: As an English speaker, I don't think I would generally refer to wind this way. If it were blowing "along the outside wall", I would not refer to the window, but the wall itself.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt anyone would use your example, since inside the room you would not be able to tell the wind direction without some other visual clue.

In your situation, I would say:

> The wind is blowing **through** the window.

For wind blowing parallel to the window, you would only know that the wind is *not* blowing through the window. If the wind was blowing leaves, you might say;

> The wind is blowing leaves **past** the window.

I can't envision using *across* in this context.

Comment: What about rain? Say, rain is either parallel or perpendicular to the window. Can I say the direction of rain is towards the window/across the window?

Comment: In normal circumstances rain cannot fall parallel to a window and strike it, nor can rain fall perpendicular (other than very high wind conditions like a tornado or hurricane). So I would just say "It is raining **on/against** the window". At a more horizontal direction, usually wind is involved. In that case, you could say "The wind is blowing the rain **against** the window."

Comment: By parallel what I meant was, say the window in my room is a sliding window which i can slide left to right and vice-versa. Say, rain in falling from left to right such that no water is coming inside the room even if the window is open as opposed to rain being aimed inside the room. This is what I intended to say when I used the word 'parallel', so what is the right word in this context?

Comment: In the case where water is not actually hitting the window, there really isn't any direct relationship between them. A statement should be about what you see or what the rain is doing.